# 408 Request Timeout Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client

Tags: wordpress, http, authentication, buddypress

I got 408 Request Time-out error when i try to login with below error message

Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.

I got this above error when i use login widget in home page http://www.imchennai.com/ and also in theme’s login page http://www.imchennai.com/login/

But in wordpress inbuilt login page http://www.imchennai.com/wp-login.php am not having this error. Can anyone suggest me the solution?

For testing check yourself with below login details

Username : demo

Password : demo

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it now using the below links

http://buddypress.org/support/topic/bp-default-sidebar-login-not-working/#post-166903

http://buddypress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5080

bp-default theme itself having this issue in current buddypress version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Put this thing in your httpd.conf

`<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
  RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
</IfModule>`